# Opening a parquet directory [arrowcpp]

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm trying to open a hive-partitioned parquet, which is essentially a nested directory with many little parquet fragments at the bottom level. When working with Python (using `pyarrow`), I can just use `read_table` on the top directory that has a .parquet at the end of the name, and everything is handled automatically. If I'm working with just a single file in C++, I can use a `std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile>` instance to read from it, but of course it does not work on a directory.

Basically, I want to find a set of tools with the starting point marked as ***?*** below:

*Python*:

**open single file** -> `pyarrow.parquet.read_table`

**open directory (partitioned dataset)** -> `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset`

*C++*:

**open single file** -> `std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile>`

**open directory (partitioned dataset)** -> ***?***